# Memory deallocation in HashMap while removing elements

Tags: java, memory-management, hashmap

While adding new elements to HashMap, the capacity of HashMap is increased when it's threshold level is reached. Likewise, will it's size be shrunk while removing elements and a lot of buckets become empty? If so, how is it done? If not, won't cause memory leakage?

Answer (score 1):

> Likewise, will it's size be shrunk while removing elements and a lot of buckets become empty?

Nope.

> If not, won't cause memory leakage?

Yes, if you hold onto it.  But that situation is actually super rare: expanding a map to a large size, removing lots of entries, and not expanding it out again is the only way you'd get significant losses here, and that's just not a thing that happens very often in practice.

Comment: It should be emphasized that we’re only talking about an oversized array here. The unused buckets are still `null` and not referencing additional objects.